# Unable to run a shell script as a systemd service

Tags: bash, scripts, systemd

I have a small script to transform midi input notes to media functions (volume up, next song, etc). It looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
aseqdump -p "CMD MM-1" | \
while IFS=" ," read src ev1 ev2 ch label1 data1 label2 data2 rest; do
    case "$ev1 $ev2 $data1" in
        "Note on 32" ) xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume ;;
        "Note on 31" ) xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume ;;
        "Note on 51" ) xdotool key XF86AudioMute ;;
        "Note on 28" ) xdotool key XF86AudioPrev ;;
        "Note on 29" ) xdotool key XF86AudioNext ;;
        "Note on 50" ) xdotool key XF86AudioPlay ;;
    esac
done
```

I can launch it from the terminal and it remains unable to receive commands until I press `ctrl+c`. So far so good. My question is, how can I use this script as a service so that I don't have to worry about it being in a visible terminal and running on reboot?

I have a service file in `/etc/systemd/system/` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script for Sync

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/midi2keys.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I believe you should start your service as a user service instead `/etc/systemd/user` then `systemctl --user enable ...`

Answer (score 2):

To survive the reboot you should save your script in

`cd /opt/systemd/` then `sudo chmod a+x YOURSCRIPTFILENAME`

then create a service like

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/YOURSERVICENAME.service
```

Then Edit the file by typing `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/YOURSERVICENAME.service` and then typing in :

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script for Sync

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/midi2keys.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then Ctrl + X to exit , Y to save and enter to write file.

Now to install the service and ensure it loads at boot time type:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable YOURSERVICENAME.service
```

reboot the machine.